# Получение обновлений виджета scrolledtext в tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

При изменении текста в scrolledtext необходимо каждый раз выводить на экран значение True

Answer (score 0):

```
scrolledtext = scrolledtext.ScrolledText(window)
scrolledtext.bind('<Key>', lambda x: print(True))
```